There's no frame callback execution between two long macro task
I found a confusing behavior of Chromium:
Event if a macro task runs for a long time, 99ms eg., the main thread still executes the next macro task in queue instead of running the requestAnimationFrame callback immediately.
Here is my test html page, you can directly copy it into a plain text file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function logWithTimestamp(...args) {
            console.log(`#${performance.now().toFixed(4)}#: `, ...args);
        }

        function pinMacroTaskTime(key) {
            logWithTimestamp(`scheduled macro task, task: ${key || ""}`);
        }

        function pinMicroTaskTime(key) {
            Promise.resolve().then(() => logWithTimestamp(`scheduled micro task, task: ${key}`));
        }


        function pinFrameTime(key) {
            requestAnimationFrame((deadline) => {
                logWithTimestamp(`${key} frame, timestamp: ${deadline}`);
            });
        }

        function loop(s) {
            const now = performance.now();
            while (performance.now() - now < s) { }
        }

        function scheduleMacroTask(options) {
            const { task, delay = 0, duration = 0 } = options || {};
            setTimeout(() => {
                pinMacroTaskTime(task);
                pinMicroTaskTime(task);
                pinFrameTime(task);
                loop(duration);
            }, delay);
        }

        scheduleMacroTask({
            task: 'task1',
            duration: 5,
            delay: 1000,
        });
        scheduleMacroTask({
            task: 'task2',
            duration: 99,
            delay: 1006,
        });
        scheduleMacroTask({
            task: 'task3',
            duration: 99,
            delay: 1006,
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>

Here is the Chrome DevTool log result:
#1039.8000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task1
#1045.2000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task1
#1045.4000#:  task1 frame, timestamp: 1035
#1045.6000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task2
#1144.8000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task2
#1145.0000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task3
#1244.0000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task3
#1244.1000#:  task2 frame, timestamp: 1041
#1244.1000#:  task3 frame, timestamp: 1041

FireFox as a contrast:
#1032.0000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task1
#1039.0000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task1
#1039.0000#:  task1 frame, timestamp: 1033.9
#1048.0000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task2
#1148.0000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task2
#1148.0000#:  task2 frame, timestamp: 1049.06
#1148.0000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task3
#1247.0000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task3
#1247.0000#:  task3 frame, timestamp: 1147.6

I expect it that there is a requestAnimationFrame callback execution between task2 and task 3.
This's true in FireFox, but false in Chrome. T.T~~~~  Why?
After several tests, I find when the duration of task2 set to 100ms,the frame callback log will show up!!!
scheduleMacroTask({
    task: 'task1',
    duration: 5,
    delay: 1000,
});
scheduleMacroTask({
    task: 'task2',
    duration: 100,
    delay: 1006,
});
scheduleMacroTask({
    task: 'task3',
    duration: 99,
    delay: 1006,
});

/*
#1050.6000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task1
#1056.0000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task1
#1056.2000#:  task1 frame, timestamp: 1051.2
#1058.1000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task2
#1158.3000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task2
#1158.6000#:  task2 frame, timestamp: 1057.3
#1159.8000#:  scheduled macro task, task: task3
#1259.3000#:  scheduled micro task, task: task3
#1259.8000#:  task3 frame, timestamp: 1154.2

*/


Is 100ms a hard-coded magic threshold in Chromium?
